# jQuery do something if page is scrolled down to class name

Tags: jquery, height, show, offset, scrolltop

I want to have a div appear if I go to less than or equal to a class on a page.

Ie.  I want this box to appear once the page is scrolled down to a certain class.  By scrolling downward on the page I want this box to still appear up until I go back ABOVE the class.

Currently this does not do the exact mentioned above, rather it hides when I scroll above or below it.   I need to modify the code somehow:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
    }

    var myelement = $('.pricebox'); // the element to act on if viewable
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $('#prodbar').show();
        } else {
            $('#prodbar').hide();// do something when element is not viewable
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
```

to

```
return (elemTop <= docViewBottom);
```

And this will show and hide the element as you intended:

```
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
        $('#prodbar').slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $('#prodbar').slideUp("slow");
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKeuR/2/

Comment: Thank you this worked for the most part.  It now more correctly shows when scrolling to the bottom of the page.   However when I scroll back up it still shows and is not hiding.

Comment: Yeah I didnt have the view large enough to notice, thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding your trying to make an element show when the window is within the bounds of the selected element.

Using the documentTop in both examples you could check that the window top is more then or equal to the element top and ensure that the window top is less then or equal to the element bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop, docViewBottom, elemTop, elemBottom;

        docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return docViewTop >= elemTop && docViewTop <= elemBottom;
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var myelement = $('.pricebox'); // the element to act on if viewable
        if (isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $('#prodbar').show();
        } else {
            $('#prodbar').hide(); // do something when element is not viewable
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/halfcube/Xb5Yq/

Comment: Nop, he was trying to show the element if the viewport was from the top of some other element to the bottom of the page.